# Parameter in callback inside request animation polyfill

Tags: javascript

I read the following request animation polyfill. However, I cannot understand why the author put `currTime + timeToCall` parameter into the `callback` in `setInterval`:

```
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
                callback(currTime + timeToCall);
            },
```

Here is the full polyfill code snippet:

```
// Set up requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame for use in the game code
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame =
        window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||
        window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
                callback(currTime + timeToCall);
            },
            timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This parameters in the polyfill are used to cover the `requestAnimationFrame` specification.
If you intend to use time control in your animations your callback should provide a timestamp parameter.
`(currTime + timeToCall)` in polyfill provides a more accurate timestamp for animations than the simple use of `setTimeout`.

```
var now, timeBetweenFrames, lastTime;

function animation (timestamp) {
  now  = timestamp; // the value of timestamp is changing
  timeSinceLastFrame = now - lastTime; // time between frames in miliseconds
  lastTime = now;       

  // ... performe your animations

  // you can use the timeSinceLastFrame value, for example, 
  // to interpolate the position of your objects,
  // making the animation reacts equally, independent of performance scenarios

  // here is an example:
  // ... 

  // if you have an object named player, with moves depending on his velocity
  // update the player position
  player.x += player.velocity.x * (timeSinceLastFrame/1000);
  player.y += player.velocity.y * (timeSinceLastFrame/1000);
  // note that timeSinceLastFrame/1000 is the time in seconds instead of miliseconds
  // draw the player on the screen
  player.draw();

  // ...

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

function start() {
  lastTime = Date.now() // or performance.now() like described below this code snippet
  requestAnimationFrame(animation);  // let this party begin
}

start();
```

Be careful, the `timestamp` parameter sent to your callback if the browser have native `requestAnimationFrame` support is a time in the same format as used in `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()`. This is valid for some new versions of browsers, like Chrome. See this HTML5 Rocks article for a more detailed explanation:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision